# ASP.NET MVC 2 - Binding To Abstract Model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, abstract-class, model-binding

If i have the following strongly-typed view:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<XXX.DomainModel.Core.Locations.Location>" %>
```

Where **Location** is an abstract class.

And i have the following Controller, which accepts a strongly-typed Model via a **POST:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Location model)
```

I get a runtime error stating *"Cannot Create Abstract Class*

Which of course makes sense. However - i'm not sure what the best solution is here.

I have many concrete types (around 8), and this is a view where you can only edit properties of the abstract class.

What i've **tried** to do is create overloads for all the different concrete types, and perform my logic in a common method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(City model)
{
   UpdateLocationModel(model);
   return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(State model)
{
   UpdateLocationModel(model);
   return View(model);
}
```

etc etc

And then:

```
[NonAction]
private void UpdateLocationModel (Location model)
{
   // ..snip - update model
}
```

**But this doesn't work either**, MVC complains the action methods are ambiguous (also makes sense).

What do we do? Can we simply not bind to an abstract model?

Comment: Good question. Interested in seeing the answers!

Comment: I'm curious if you ever found a better way to handle this?

Comment: @Mystere Man - nope. I haven't had to do it again. If i did, i would do what the accepted answer suggests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about writing a custom model binder for this abstract class:

```
public class CustomBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        // TODO: based on some request parameter choose the proper child type
        // to instantiate here
        return new Child();
    }
}
```

This make sense only if you have a form where input elements are inserted dynamically based on some user action. In this case you need to pass some additional parameter to indicate which concrete class you need. Otherwise I would stick to concrete view models as action parameters.

Comment: Well this is a very simple view, edit fields for properties on the abstract model. So i didn't want to have to "duplicate" this HTML across multiple strongly-typed views. I'll have a look into custom model binders - as i do know the child type when i render the view. I'll try it out the office tomorrow - cheers.

Comment: Okay i've had a read of model binders, and i agree - it doesn't make sense in my scenario. I'm going to stick with the concrete view models. This would work though, so i'll accept your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can also build a generic ModelBinder that works for all of your abstract models. My solution requires you to add a hidden field to your view called '**ModelTypeName**' with the value set to the name of the concrete type that you want. 
However, it should be possible to make this thing smarter and pick a concrete type by matching type properties to fields in the view.

In your **Global.asax.cs** file in **Application_Start()**:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new CustomModelBinder();
```

**CustomModelBinder:**

```
public class CustomModelBinder2 : DefaultModelBinder 
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var modelType = bindingContext.ModelType;
        if (modelType.IsAbstract)
        {
            var modelTypeValue = controllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("ModelTypeName");
            if (modelTypeValue == null)
                throw new Exception("View does not contain ModelTypeName");

            var modelTypeName = modelTypeValue.AttemptedValue;

            var type = modelType.Assembly.GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsSubclassOf(modelType) && x.Name == modelTypeName);

            if (type != null)
            {
                var instance= bindingContext.Model ?? base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, type);
                bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => instance, type);
            }
        }
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a helpful answer, but just for anyone applying it, I suspect there could be a security risk here if the client sends back an unexpected but legitimate type name with a harmful constructor.  Right?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222533/polymorphic-model-binding/9813472#9813472

Comment: @uosɐſ: only in the case MVC is trying to map to a subclass (see `.IsSubclassOf(...)`) of an expected abstract class used in the controller action signature, or one of the controller action signature objects' child properties. And then it has to have a "harmful" constructor. I'm thinking of using this code. Can you give an example of such a security risk?

Comment: Hmm, I guess I didn't notice that restriction when I asked that.  I can't think of anything now.

Comment: @Joel If you plan to use this code, please see my edits. I have been using this version in production and it is working very well.

Comment: @Kelly: Updated the model binder too (set `bindingContext.ModelMetadata`) before using it; [released on gist for comparison](https://gist.github.com/2415633). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw it out there - I'm very much interested in what others might answer, but this is what I ended up doing in the case where I had a similar situation;

Basically, I did not use the model class as a parameter in the Action method, instead passing in `FormCollection` and testing a couple known discriminators to figure out which type to create/edit, then used `TryUpdateModel` from there.

It seemed there might be a better way, but I'd never gotten around to thinking about it more.

Comment: Yeah, that was my next step! :) But awww, i wan't the strongly typed goodness. :)

Comment: It's delicious, and nutritious; Part of this complete breakfast!