# Flexible dynamic routing for MVC 3 Multi-tenant architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, multi-tenant

I want to create a multitenant web site where each tenant can create multiple portals 
    similar to what Dotnetnuke does.
    I want to provide a flexible dynamic routing (that can take effect at run-time e.g. 
    I can add a tenant at run time) like outlined below.
    I also like to allow/restrict tenants to certain modules (Areas(group of Controllers) 
    for coarse grained access control or Controllers for fine grained access control ) and 
    Controllers Actions for the finest access control.

- Tenant doesn't own a domain or subdomain - uses SaaS host domain name)

  ```
  tenant1.saasplatform.com ( implicitly means has /portal0 suffix )
  tenant1.saasplatform.com/portal0
  tenant1.saasplatform.com/portal1

  saasplatform.com/tenant1  ( implicitly means has /portal0 suffix )
  saasplatform.com/tenant1/portal0
  saasplatform.com/tenant1/portal1
  ```
- Tenant owns a domain or subdomain)

  ```
  tenant1.com ( implicitly means has /portal0 suffix )
  tenant1.com/portal0
  tenant1.com/portal0

  tenant1.com  ( implicitly means has portal0. prefix )
  portal0.tenant1.com
  portal1.tenant1.com
  ```

  ---

Given various combination I want to extract tenantkey based on configuration per tenant.
    I want also to extract portal number (it can be a unique number for a portal or a unique name).

Everything after portal number will be resolved via normal routing values `{controller}/{action}`

`tenant1.com[/portal0]` "[]" content inside the brackets in optional and it will be treated as "portal0"

```
{tenantkey}{portal0}

tenant1.saasplatform.com[/portal0] 
{tenantkey}.saasplatform.com}{portal0}
{tenantkey}.othersaasplatform.com}{portal0}

[portal0.]tenant1.com
{portalkey}.{tenantkey}
```

Some good ideas shown below. The article is quite old. I was wondering if there is something  new in MVC 3?

http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx

[Tenant-specific routes for dynamically loaded modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246773/tenant-specific-routes-for-dynamically-loaded-modules)

Answer (score 0):

If the content of each portal is fetched from a database, your best bet is to hook to an extensibility point.
http://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=1358