# MVC app doesn't run with a generic method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics

I wanted to create a method in my Base controller that would take a list and return it as a SelectList. I wrote a method, and the site compiles, but I get this message:

> Cannot call action method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem] GetSelectList[T](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T], System.String, System.String, System.String, System.Object)' on controller 'PublicationSystem.Controllers.BaseController' because the action method is a generic method.
>   Parameter name: methodInfo

I'm wondering what I did wrong. Here's the code:

```
public partial class BaseController : Controller
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectList<T>
    (
        IEnumerable<T> itemList, 
        string textField,
        string valueField,
        string defaultPrompt = "", 
        object defaultValue = null)
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> returnList = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultPrompt))
        {
            returnList = Enumerable.Repeat(
                new SelectListItem { Value = (string)defaultValue, Text = defaultPrompt },
                count: 1);
        }

        var textProp = typeof (T).GetProperty(textField);
        var valueProp = typeof (T).GetProperty(valueField);

        returnList = returnList.Concat
            (itemList
                .Select(x =>
                    new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = Convert.ToString(valueProp.GetValue(x)),
                        Text = Convert.ToString(textProp.GetValue(x)),
                    }).Distinct().ToList());

        return returnList.ToList();
    }
}

public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); // Errors here
        //..
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you call the generic method the right way

Comment: `GetSelectList<T>` is generic. MVC doesn't know what to pass for `T`. Instead explain why you made the method generic. See for example [Generic type in MVC controller action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20328919/generic-type-in-mvc-controller-action).

Comment: I will pass in a list, but it could be a list of almost anything.

Comment: Try to pass a list of objects then. Generics will not work in your case.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your method is `public` in controller class. Asp.Net will see this method as an action method.

You can't use generic methods for action. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23367384/3432471).

If you want to use this method on derived classes(your controllers). Make your method `protected`.

Comment: 'Asp.Net will see this method as an action method.' was the key point, thank you. That sheds a new light on how the inherited controller works and what should and shouldn't be there.

Comment: @MKenyonII If it helped you can mark as an answer to guide other people.

Comment: I get this error even when decorating the method as [NonAction], which is annoying as that can make unit testing a bit more tedious, but then I take the hint and move it to a utility class instead which is where it belongs.

Comment: @Etherman don't write unit test for controller. That means don't do any business other than orchestrating at controller level.

Answer (score 0):

I removed this method. I turned it into an Extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`. Here's what I'm doing now:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AsSelectList<T>
    (
        this IEnumerable<T> dataList,
        string textField,
        string valueField,
        string defaultPrompt = "",
        object defaultValue = null)
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> returnList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultPrompt))
        {
            returnList = Enumerable.Repeat(
                new SelectListItem { Value = (string)defaultValue, Text = defaultPrompt },
                count: 1);
        }

        var textProp = typeof(T).GetProperty(textField);
        var valueProp = typeof(T).GetProperty(valueField);

        returnList = returnList.Concat
            (dataList
                .Select(x =>
                    new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = Convert.ToString(valueProp.GetValue(x)),//x["valueField"],
                        Text = Convert.ToString(textProp.GetValue(x)),//x.["textField"]
                    }).Distinct().ToList());

        return returnList;
    }
}
```