# Pass Json object as object of type System.Object or Interface not working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

Class:

public class ClassNameA :ISomeInterface {
   }
   public class ClassNameB :ISomeInterface {
   }

From javascript:

```
var reqP = { 'Id': id, 'Name':name };
var ReqParams = { 'ReqParams': reqP };
var obj = { 'ClassNameA': ReqParams };

makeAjaxCall("POST",
        JSON.stringify(obj), '/ControllerName/someMethod/', 'html',
```

Action method looks like:

```
public ActionResult someMethod(object obj){
    // call comes to this method but obj is not populated. 
}

public ActionResult someMethod(ISomeInterface obj){
    // call comes to this method but throws exception. 
    // Exception : Cannot instantiate interface. but i am passing class object.
}
```

from JavaScript I will pass object of a concrete class type which implements `ISomeInterface` so that I can have multiple implementations. Concrete Class can of any one of the two types.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: You need a defined model as the parameter.

Comment: then it becomes tightly coupled with that defined model type. i do not want that. so if I use generic type then I can use that to go to particular implementation based on object type after casting.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work. The model binder needs a concrete type to be able to create an instance and bind the values.

`object` is a concrete type and can be created using [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.activator.createinstance), but it doesn't have any properties that will match the data you receive.

The interface (or abstract types) cannot be created, since they're not concrete types. It's a simple as that.

If the JSON contained some hint about the type, it migth be possible to implement a custom model binder to create the instances for you. You can read more about the model binding process [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx).

Comment: yes the json object has information of class type. when i look in firbug then it shows me object with concrete class name and populated properties.. so i was thinking to use reflection to get the type(object.getType()) and then create its instance and perform rest of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The default model binder is not going to be able to figure out what to do. Let's just go through the exercise with some sample interfaces to show why. Say you have this:

```
public ActionResult SomeMethod(ISomeInterface obj)
{
    // ...
}
```

...and say you have these two implemenetations:

```
class ClassA : ISomeInterface
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

class ClassB : ISomeInterface
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

...and say this JSON is posted:

```
{ "Name": "Some Value" }
```

How would the model binder know which class to use? Would it search all defined classes in all assemblies to find all implementations of the interface? And if so, even if it had smart selection logic based on properties, how would it select between `ClassA` or `ClassB`, both of which are compatible?

What you may want to do is either use a type like `Dictionary<string, object>` that you know will be compatible, `dynamic`, or go with a concrete class that is a union of everything you need. Alternately, you can create a custom model binder with its own logic for selecting the class you want to instantiate. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222533/polymorphic-model-binding) for more details.