# mvc alternative to using if-else for multiple views and controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, code-duplication

I want to create a model-view-controller without having if-else for individual controls, or  having to duplicate these to handle different on-screen controls.
Currently I have:-

//controller

```
public ActionResult DisplayThing1(int thingType, string thingName){

  Thing1Model model = new Thing1Model();
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DisplayThing1(Thing1Model model)
{
  Save(model);
  return RedirectToAction("DisplayThing1");
}
```

// model

```
public class Thing1Model()
{
 public int type {get; set; }
 public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

// view

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(....))
{
 @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.type);
 @Html.LabelForI(m=>m.Name);
}
```

I have pretty much duplicated controller for `Thing2Model`, the model itself is

```
public class Thing2Model()
{
 public int type {get; set; }
 public string Name {get; set;}
 public DateTime MyDate {get; set;}
}
```

A combined view would look like the following.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(....))
{
 @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.type);
 @Html.LabelForI(m=>m.Name);
 @if(type == "2")
 {
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.MyDate);
 }
}
```

I am looking for a better option to avoid `@if` as well as duplicated code

EDIT:
Adding onto @W92 answer. We also need to change the model binder to support inherited models. 
Otherwise, in the the view for this code, MVC won't understand how to put child properties.

[Polymorphic model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222533/polymorphic-model-binding)

Comment: you tried to use partialView or Html.Action()? (which return PartialView). In Html.Action you can put a parameters etc. It sounds pretty good. For action which service Html.Action good's use  attribute: `[ChildActionOnly()]` (read in google) or ask for more details :-)

Comment: i thought of using a partial view but the common fields need to display alongside the uncommon ones. see http://www.gliffy.com/go/publish/image/6238620/L.png. How do I do this with a partial view?

Comment: I can't understand the problem, could you explain me it in more details?

Comment: can you post some example code for partial view in this scenario? 
Can it be done inside beginform(){}, will the partial be for the date or the name and type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your problem exactly, but pretty good, well sorry for any mistakes.

```
public class Thing1Model()
{
 public int type {get; set; }
 public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Thing2Model() : Thing1Model
{
  public DateTime MyDate {get; set;}
}
```

and in your View: //model2

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(....))
{
     @Html.PartialView("_myForm");
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.MyDate);
}
```

and `_myForm` has a model of Thing1Model with content:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.type);
 @Html.LabelForI(m=>m.Name);
```

but when will be in View (thing1), only use:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(...))
{
 @Html.PartialView("_myForm");
}
```

Comment: Nice! i didn't think of that. So will 1) the controller just use the parent model to get, post? 2)Can the view be strongly typed on the parent model?

Comment: model's using for present your data (textBox, label etc). It return's only html. Test it on the browse with f12. It's a neccesary information. I prefer for you to learn with microsoftacademy :-) Here's three great courses (one from other site):
http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/introduction-to-asp-net-mvc
http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/developing-asp-net-mvc-4-web-applications-jump-start
and
http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m6-ajax&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building

IT REALLY WORTH! :-)