# Use custom model binder from different assembly and instantiate object from same

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, custom-model-binder

I have a class library which includes a custom MVC model binder to instantiate various concrete types which derive from an abstract class. The model binder is almost identical to the one described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7222639/457199).

It works fine when using it from within the same Visual Studio Solution that also includes an MVC web application for testing.

My problem is that having created a nuget package from the assembly and included it in a totally separate MVC application the model binder no longer works, despite having configured it correctly in Global.asax.cs.

After some hair pulling I recreated the model binder directly in the separate MVC app, and as I was doing so I noticed that the overridden `CreateModel()` method in the binder is protected. It now gets executed and I suspect the protected keyword has something to do with it but I would like someone to explain why exactly.

Even with the 'local' modelbinder there are more problems. When it executes, and tries to instantiate the concrete object, I get an exception `Could not load type XXXX from assembly { separate MVC project assembly name}` so it seems the model binder is unable to load types from outside its own assembly.

Can anyone give me more information on why this happens and what I can do to work around it? Bearing in mind I need the model binder and models to reside in the class library not in the MVC assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I was being stupid. It turns out that a few assumptions led me on a wild goose chase.

The ModelBinder was executing correctly to start with. My viewmodel had nested properties which were also abstract base types and required the model binder but I hadn't put the hidden fields in the view to identify their concrete type, nor had I added them to the Global.asax configuration. Once I did this everything started to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you did, binding to models in a different assembly, but I needed a different solution. I used the same model binding example that you linked to, and I also got the same exception: `Could not load type XXXX from assembly`

I ended up needing to use the AssemblyQualifiedName for each concrete type. So my views contain this:

`@Html.Hidden("ModelType", Model.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName)`

Instead of this:

`@Html.Hidden("ModelType", Model.GetType())`

I'm still wondering why this was necessary, since the default model binder can load types from the assembly in question.