# asp.net mvc polymorphic model binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222533/polymorphic-model-binding) example to the exact with a minor change in my ViewModel

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class FooViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Options { get; set; }
}
```

How to make the `IEnumerable` property in the above example work?

Comment: What do you mean _How to make it work_?

Comment: Probably you do have typo use `IEnumerable<string>` instead of `Ienumerable<string>`.

Comment: What is the issue when you run the code flow?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the title, I'm assuming your question is how to post `Options` when your action accepts only `BaseViewModel`, i.e.:

```
public ActionResult Foo(BaseViewModel model)
{
    // do something with `model.Options`
}
```

If that's the case, the answer is you can't. The result of a post is just a collection of key-value pair strings. The modelbinder is tasked with taking this data and transforming it into the parameter(s) your action accepts, instantiating classes and setting properties as appropriate. However, it's not psychic. It needs guidance in the form of your action parameter types. Given that, based on the action, it's going to instantiate `BaseViewModel` and then see which properties on that it can fill. It will fill `Id`, but then it's done. It will simply discard the rest of the posted data, because there's nothing more it can do on `BaseViewModel`. The modelbinder has no way of knowing that `FooViewModel` is actually what you want. If you need an instance of `FooViewModel`, then you must type your action parameter as that. Nothing else will work.