# Overload action with different parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have several model classes inherited from common base (e.g. `Class1`, `Class2` inherits from `CommonClass`). I would like to write separate overloaded controller action which would have each of these model classes as parameter. For example:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult MyAction(Class1 data)
    {
       // handle data here
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult MyAction(Class2 data)
    {
       // handle data here
    }
```

Is it somehow possible to achieve that? When I try to simply write those action methods, MVC throws `System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException`.

I have also tried to write single action with base class as parameter and then cast data to specific class, but this gives me `null`.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult MyAction(CommonClass data)
    {
        if(data.IsSomething)
        {
            var castedData = data as Class1;
            // process casted data
        }
        else
        {
            var castedData = data as Class2;
            // process casted data
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have multiple actions with the same name and HTTP verb on the same controller. You will need to have different action names and routes.

Alternatively you may checkout [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7222639/29407) in which I illustrate how you could write a custom model binder and achieve polymorphic binding (your second attempt with the base class).

Answer (score 1):

You could decorate your action with the `[ActionName]` annotation. Like this:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("OtherName")]
public JsonResult MyAction(Class1 data)
{
   // handle data here
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MyAction(Class2 data)
{
   // handle data here
}
```

And with that you can use to put names with characters that .NET do not allow, like `[ActionName("This-Example")]`