# MVC3 View With Abstract Property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, inheritance, model, abstract-class

Consider the following.

#### Models

```
public class DemographicsModel
{
    public List<QuestionModel> Questions { get; set; }
}

//Does not work at all if this class is abstract.
public /*abstract*/ class QuestionModel
{
    //...
}

public class ChooseOneQuestionModel : QuestionModel
{
    //...
}

public class ChooseManyQuestionModel : QuestionModel
{
    //...
}

public class RichTextQuestionModel : QuestionModel
{
    //...
}

public class TextQuestionModel : QuestionModel
{
    //...
}
```

#### Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Demographics(DemographicsModel model)
{
    //...
}
```

My view would have a `DemographicsModel` with numerous question of all the varying types as shown above. After the form is completed and `POST`ed back to the server, the `Questions` property of the `Demographics model` is re-populated with the correct number of questions but they are all of type `QuestionModel` instead of the concrete type.

How do I make this thing understand what type to instantiate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frazell's answer would have worked if my root model was the one that was abstract. However, that's not the case for me so what ended up working was this: http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DerivedTypeModelBinder&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: I've posted an answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417888/mvc-3-model-binding-a-sub-type-abstract-class-or-interface/

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC's built in Model Binding doesn't support Abstract classes. You can roll your own to handle the Abstract class though see [ASP.NET MVC 2 - Binding To Abstract Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012217/asp-net-mvc-2-binding-to-abstract-model) .

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to jump in here, even though it seems you've already solved it.

But would

```
public class DemographicsModel<T> Where T : QuestionModel
{
    public List<T> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

Work?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Demographics(DemographicsModel<ChooseOneQuestionModel> model)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Not in my case because the concrete `QuestionModel` classes can be commingled in the `List`. Thanks.