# Custom polymorphic model binder doesn't bind properties on derived type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Here's my custom model binder which is used to instantiate a derived class.

```
public class LocationModalBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
        Type modelType)
    {
        var type = bindingContext.ModelName + "." + "type";

        Type typeToInstantiate;

        switch ((string) bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(type).RawValue)
        {
            case "store":
            {
                typeToInstantiate = typeof (Store);
                break;
            }
            case "billing":
            {
                typeToInstantiate = typeof(LocationReference);
                break;
            }
            case "alternate":
            {
                typeToInstantiate = typeof(Address);
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                throw new Exception("Unknown location identifier.");
            }
        }

        return base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, typeToInstantiate);
    }
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't bind properties on the sub type. Only properties on the base type `Location`. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that calling `return base.CreateModel` is fine as you have attempted.

I solved it by adding the following before the `return base.CreateModel` line:

```
bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, typeToInstantiate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did this from here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/9428558/221683

I don't understand how many of the examples of this type of model binder have worked without these assignments.

```
public class LocationModalBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext,
        Type modelType)
    {
        var type = bindingContext.ModelName + "." + "type";

        Type typeToInstantiate;

        switch ((string) bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(type).RawValue)
        {
            case "store":
            {
                typeToInstantiate = typeof (Store);
                break;
            }
            case "billing":
            {
                typeToInstantiate = typeof(LocationReference);
                break;
            }
            case "alternate":
            {
                typeToInstantiate = typeof(Address);
                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                throw new Exception("Unknown location identifier.");
            }
        }

        var model = Activator.CreateInstance(typeToInstantiate);

        bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, typeToInstantiate);
        bindingContext.ModelMetadata.Model = model;

        return model;
    }
}
```