# Model Binding with Model inheritance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I had a Model with a property that is an abstract class

```
public class MyModel
{
     public Foo Property { get; set; }
}
```

I have several implementations of `Foo`, each with their own EditorTemplate.  Each implementation also has fields unique to it.  Let's call these `AFoo`, `BFoo`, and `CFoo`.

Now, when I post my form, the model binder will try to create these all as `Foo`.  Obviously, this will not work, because `Foo` is abstract.

Short of writing `Model.GetType()` to a hidden field, then using a custom model binder, is there a way to tell the default model binder how to correctly construct the correct type?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7222639/1625737

Comment: In addition to haim770 comment, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417888/mvc-3-model-binding-a-sub-type-abstract-class-or-interface

Comment: @haim770 That's kinda what I was thinking when I said creating a custom model binder.  I didn't know if there was any magic built in before I did that.