# Custom Model Binder for List nested inside a wrapper model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding, custom-model-binder

I have the following model:

```
public class SidebarViewModel
{
    public SidebarViewModel()
    {
        Filters = new List<FilterViewModel>();
    }

    public List<FilterViewModel> Filters { get; set; }
}
```

And each Filter looks like this:

```
public abstract class FilterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public bool Visible { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public abstract string DisplayName { get; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string ModelType { get { return GetType().Name; } }
}
```

And there are filter subtypes that look like this:

```
public class TextFilter : FilterViewModel
{
    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get { return "Some Name Here"; }
    }
}
```

When the post occurs, the entire SidebarViewModel should be posted to the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Filter(SidebarViewModel sidebar)
{
    // Stuff here.
}
```

In order to get the SidebarViewModel to bind, I tried writing a custom ModelBinder for FilterViewModel objects:

```
public class FilterModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
        var filterTypeValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName + ".ModelType");
        var filterType = Type.GetType(filterTypeValue.ToString(), true);
        var model = Activator.CreateInstance(filterType);

        bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, filterType);

        return model;
    }
}
```

And registered that ModelBinder in Global.asax.cs:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(FilterViewModel), new FilterModelBinder());
```

Finally, the view:

```
@model SidebarViewModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Filter", SessionVars.ControllerName, new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "tool-wrapper",
    LoadingElementId = "loading-image",
    HttpMethod = "POST"
}))
{
    <fieldset>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Filters)

        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit">Submit Options</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

And EditorTemplate:

```
@model FilterViewModel

<div class="control-group">
    @Html.Label(Model.DisplayName, new { @class = "control-label" })

    <div class="controls">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Value)

        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DisplayName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ModelType)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Visible)
    </div>
</div>
```

**The problem is that when the sidebar is posted, the FilterModelBinder is never called.** Do I need *another* custom model binder for SidebarViewModel? If so, how would I call the FilterModelBinder for each filter in the sidebar's list?

Comment: Have you seen this thread => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417888/mvc-3-model-binding-a-sub-type-abstract-class-or-interface ?

Comment: Yep, I did, but I'm still having the same problem. My SidebarViewModel, FilterViewModel, and TextFilter classes map map pretty much directly to the MyModel, MyBaseClass, and MyDerivedClass classes from the accepted answer in that thread. When I set my custom model binder as the default binder, the binder does execute, and the modelType is SidebarViewModel, but the list of FilterViewModels are never run through the custom binder.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it ended up being an issue with my RuntimeRoute registration. There was an invalid one in there, and removing it fixed my binding issue.