# Mvc5 pass model to Layout Page

Tags: layout, asp.net-mvc-5, controller

I have an MVC 5 site with adminlte template. It's work fine. Now I need pass to some data to _layout page. I need pass to _layout page same info as number of alert, number of email, alert list ecc. I read same document about BaseController where do this operation, i.e. read this data and put in a model, or create an abstract model and put this info into. But is not possibile create this model one time (i.e. on user login controller) and share it in all request without re-create it every controller call? Pratically, as a global singleton variabile.
Thanks.

Comment: so you basically want a default view model which contains repeated porperties like email & info...??  &  include this view model in all the entity classes so that the same properties dont have to be created again & again.. am i correct ?

Comment: Yes. Same properties. If possibile I want generate this model only one time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a good usecase to use a ChildAction which can be called from the layout view.

So start by creating a view model to represent the data

```
public class AlertVm
{
    public int EmailCount { set; get; }
    public int NotificationCount { set; get; }
}
```

Now create an action method which creates an object of this, set the values and pass to a partial view

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Alerts()
{
    var vm = new AlertVm {EmailCount = 4, NotificationCount = 2};
    return PartialView(vm);
}
```

Now your Alerts.cshtml view, which is strongly typed to our view model, you can render whatever you want.

```
<div>
    <p>@Model.EmailCount emails</p>
    <p>@Model.NotificationCount notifications</p>
</div>
```

And this action method can be invoked from the `_Layout.cshtml` view.

```
<div>@Html.Action("Alerts", "Home")</div>
```

With this approach, you do not need worry about the creating a view model for every single action. (Ex : Your about page which does not need a view model usually)

Comment: This is a good solution! Thanks. The problem is that in ActionResult  I need to access db data (i.e. EmailCount is a entityFramework call). Every page have same delay.

Comment: what is the problem with that ? Just query it using entity framework.

Comment: There are no problems. But, do query one time will be the best solution. Try to use Session variable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can create a base view model & make all the model inherit it

```
public class MyModel
{
    public MyBaseClass BaseClass { get; set; }
}

public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public virtual string MyName
    {
        get
        {
            return "MyBaseClass";
        }
    }
}

public class MyDerievedClass : MyBaseClass
{

    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public override string MyName
    {
        get
        {
            return "MyDerievedClass";
        }
    }
}
```

only problem is ..the default CreateModel process doesnt register this deafult view model so global.asax is where you tweek it ..

[Here is a good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417888/mvc-3-model-binding-a-sub-type-abstract-class-or-interface)

Comment: Ok. But the value in MyBaseClass is set everytime? For every controller call? I need same database call and I want do it only one time.

Comment: If you don't want to set the value ...remove the set

Comment: And add new value in controller action method every time

Comment: Ok. But it's not what I want. I need setup only one time same as singleton. Thanks